# Blocking incoming call in android 6.0

Tags: java, android

i use Permission in manifest.xml (CALL_PHONE,READ_PHONE_STATE,PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS,MODIFY_PHONE_STATE) ,ITelephony.aids i show this code in a blog .
in ITelephony.aids i write 
i want to disable all incoming call when the checkbox is checked . Code not return error but not work . i test it in android 6.0 . please help me

```
CheckBox blockAll_cb;//,blockcontacts_cb;
BroadcastReceiver CallBlocker;
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
ITelephony telephonyService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_call_controller);


    initviews();
    blockAll_cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("Error 8","Is Checked1");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CallBlocker =new BroadcastReceiver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Log.d("Error 8","Is checked2");
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    //Java Reflections
                    Class c = null;
                    try {
                        c = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Error 1",""+e);
                    }
                    Method m = null;
                    try {
                        m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d("Error 2",""+e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.d("Error 3",""+e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(telephonyManager);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        Log.d("Error 4",""+e);
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        Log.d("Error 5",""+e);
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        Log.d("Error 6",""+e);
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    telephonyManager.listen(callBlockListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                }//onReceive()
                PhoneStateListener callBlockListener = new PhoneStateListener()
                {
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
                    {
                        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
                        {
                            if(blockAll_cb.isChecked())
                            {
                                try {
                                    telephonyService.endCall();
                                    Log.d("Error End","EndCall");
                                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                    Log.d("Error 7",""+e);
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            };//BroadcastReceiver
            IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
            registerReceiver(CallBlocker, filter);
        }
    });
}
public void initviews()
{
    blockAll_cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbBlockAll);
    //blockcontacts_cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbBlockContacts);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("Error 8","Error 8");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

}
}
```

Comment: It will only work if your device is rooted else it will throw `MethodNotFound` exception

Comment: is there any way to disable all incoming call without rooted the device . please share the link or code

Comment: I am afraid there isn't. This can work below 4.4 where `getITelephony` is a public api.